# Maven "breaks" Groovy files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

I'm working on a groovy project that runs as java application in Eclipse.
Normally there are normal class files under the groovy files, but when I make a clean install of the project with maven, it deletes those java classes, so i can't run it in eclipse anymore.
Why is that so? I have another project that has the same structure without this problem.
Greetings

edit:
I made a screenshot to clear what I mean.

[image]

The PDFConverter is how I want/know it the other is what I get and can't run in Eclipse anymore

Comment: do you mean Groovy source files or compiled classes?

Comment: I edited and added a screenshot I hope that shows what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I would look at `your_project/target/classes/` directory, that's where Maven puts .class files.

Although it's not entirely clear what are you asking about.